# Notepad++ Layout of Doc Switcher, Function List,

Tags: notepad++

I'm currently using Notepad++ 7.9. I'm trying to setup notepad++ as nicely as possible.
I frequently have the following Tab/Tools or whatever they are called showing:

- Doc Switcher
- Function List
- JSON Viewer

The layout I would like, is to have Doc Switcher and Function List on the left of the editor panel and on the right have the JSON Viewer. This works to some extent: I have the JSON Viewer on the right and the two other one's on the left side, but they are 'tabbing' rather than shown next to each other - which is what I want. The tabs are no good, because switching between them, which I do a lot, requires me to click the small tabs far away from the doc or function name i want to click next.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I wanted two panels on the left and one on the right. What I've found to work is stacking two panels on top of each other:

[image: Notepad++ 3 Panel Layout]

On the left, I have one panel snapped into place. The other one is on top of it, resized to be around half the height.